# Using groupBy with resource collection laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection, laravel-controller, laravel-response

I am working on api, and using resource to send data. I want to send collection which is grouped by status. So far I have done the following:

```
public function data(){
    $collection = ModelNameResource::collection(
        ModelName::query()
            ->latest()
            ->get()
    );
    $data = $collection->groupBy('status');
    return $data;
}
```

Although I have got what I want but want to know if there is the better approach to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. Better approach in what respect? Space complexity? Time complexity? Lines of code? Cleanliness of code?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean clean code

```
public function data(){
    return ModelNameResource::collection(
        ModelName::query()
            ->latest()
            ->get()
    )->groupBy('status');
}
```